# Java 8 get field of contained Object

Tags: java

I will get all Institution- ids from InstitutionUserConnection- List (InstitutionUserConnection contains one object called institution)

Does anyone know how this works with Java 8?
This is my try but it does not work:

```
final List<InstitutionUserConnection> institutionUserConnections = ...
final List<String> institutionIds = institutionUserConnections.forEach(institution -> institution.getId());
```

Thanks a lot

**[EDIT]**

thans old fashion:

```
final List<String> institutionIds = new ArrayList<>();
for(final InstitutionUserConnection institutionUserConnection : institutionUserConnections) {
        institutionIds.add(institutionUserConnection.getInstitution().getId());
    }
```

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you'd provide a short but complete example of what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like:

```
final List<String> institutionIds = institutionUserConnections.stream()
    .map(InstitutionUserConnection::getInstitution)
    .map(Institution::getId)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You can find more similar samples eg. in the Javadoc of the [Collectors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html) class.

Comment: It almost what I want - I would need the Institution::id -> the Institution Object is inside InstitutionUserConnection Object. Is there a way to do it? such like this: **institutionUserConnections.stream().map(InstitutionUserConnection::institution::getId)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());**

Comment: @user3318489 This doesn't match the code in your question. I updated my answer, but I had to guess some of the class and method names.